# Linking to the MariaDB C Connector from Rust fails on Windows

Tags: windows, linker, mingw, rust, mariadb

I am currently working on a Rust project that requires me to connect to a MariaDB server. I have decided to create Rust bindings for the officially provided C connector, which works just fine in linux, but not on Windows.

Since only the MSVC-binaries are provided as a download, which don't work due to linker issues between the Microsft linker and the MinGW linker used for Rust that cause the program to crash when the first function is called, I tried to compile the mariadb sources myself, but even though compilation under MinGW should work as of the 2.0 release of mariadb, it fails with

> error: conflicting types for ssize_t
>   typedef SSIZE_T ssize_t

since it has already been defined in another file, and when I tried to simply remove the redefinition, other errors occured.

I tried to cross-compile it from Arch using the [mingw-w64-mariadb-connector-c package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mingw-w64-mariadb-connector-c/), which did not show any compilation errors for the connector, but when I tested the binaries on windows, it threw an undefined reference linking error for every of my C-Function declarations, which look like this:

```
extern crate libc;
use self::libc::{c_int, /*...*/};

#[link(name="mariadb", kind="dylib")]
extern {
    pub fn mysql_init(mysql: *const MYSQL) -> c_int;
    // ...
}
```

I also tried [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?167,295483,297733) suggestion for the mysql-c-connector, but the same linker errors appeared.

I am using the newest rust nightlies and MinGW-w64 v4.9.1 (the same version as in the nightlies), both 32 bit.

Comment: I can't offer much in the way of help, except to point out that the `msvc` builds of Rust on Windows are now A Thing, and close to being a first-class target.  Maybe you would have more luck with those, if the connector is only provided for MSVC?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know there were Rust builds for the native windows compiler, however my program also makes use of GTK, which (how could it be any different) is only available for MinGW. As a last resort I guess I could try to switch to a different library for the GUI-parts, but I couldn't find many good ones yet, so for now I hope I can get it to work someway else.